# Add class to label with class if radio is checked

Tags: php

I want to add a class 'checked' to the `<span class="label product-option">` when a radio button is checked and remove when a other radio is checked.

How can I extend my code for this?

```
            $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
            if ($arraySign) {
                $checked = (is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue)) ? 'checked' : '';
            } else {
                $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
            }
            $spanClass = "input-radio";
            if ($checked) {
                $spanClass = "input-radio checked";
            }

            $selectHtml .= '<li>' . '<span class="input-radio"><input type="' . $type . '" class="' . $class . ' ' . $require
                . ' product-custom-option"'
                . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"')
                . ($this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) ? '0' : ' checked="checked"')
                . ' name="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']' . $arraySign . '" id="options_' . $_option->getId()
                . '_' . $count . '" value="' . $htmlValue . '" ' . $checked . ' price="'
                . $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) . '" /></span>'
                . '<span class="label product-option' . $spanClass . '"><label for="options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count . '"><span class="option-name">'
                . $this->escapeHtml($_value->getTitle()) . '</span>' . $priceStr . '</label></span>';
            if ($_option->getIsRequire()) {
                $selectHtml .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_'
                . $count . '\').advaiceContainer = \'options-' . $_option->getId() . '-container\';'
                . '$(\'options_' . $_option->getId() . '_' . $count
                . '\').callbackFunction = \'validateOptionsCallback\';' . '</script>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</li>';
```

Comment: Please [learn to love **real** labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Why would you do that? Both in JS and CSS you can already check the status of your radio button

Comment: @SourceOverflow Sadly I can not achieve this by using CSS, because the radio input is inside a span. So I cannot use the + css rule. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes the :checked selector

Comment: @SourceOverflow The :checked selector does not work, because the radio input is inside a span. So that can not be achieve by CSS, right?

Comment: @SourceOverflow How should I achieve this already using JS? The way below from Quentin does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows that you already know how to tell if an element is checked or not, and how to set variables containing class names.

Just extend that logic.

```
$spanClass = "input-radio";
if ($checked) {
    $spanClass = "input-radio checked";
}
```

...

```
'<span class="' . $spanClass . '">'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried that but that does not seem to work. See my updated code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code should be based on `<span class="label product-option">` instead of the input-radio. But that also does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bother to check you php-code to find out how the html would look like exactly (maybe use Streams next time?), but you need to register an eventhandler like this:

(using jQuery as you seem to already be using it anyways)

```js
$('.input-radio input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  // $('.input-radio.checked').removeClass('checked'); // this works if you only have one .input-radio

  /* if you want multiple (with different names) */
  // note: template string are only available in ES6, if you use earlier versions, use the + to concatinate strings
  $(`.input-radio.checked input[type=radio][name=${this.name}]`)
    .parents('.input-radio.checked').removeClass('checked');

  $(this).parents('.input-radio').addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
/* This CSS is NOT needed and is only used for effect */

.wrapper span {
  display: block;
  /* To make them vertically aligned, usually makes no sense for span I know */
}

span.input-radio.checked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="input-radio checked">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" checked/>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input-radio">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input-radio">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input-radio">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input-radio">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input-radio">
    <label>
      Radio Button
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio"/>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

As a side note, personally I prefer using data-attributes for things like this instead of classes as that more clearly separates design from function.